# How to restrict function parameter's type to properties of struct in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Let me show an example first

```
import Foundation

struct Animal {
    struct Cat {
        let description = "It's a cat"
    }
    
    struct Dog {
        let description = "It's a dog"
    }
}

// Restrict its input to properties of struct Animal
func feedAnimal(type: Animal.Cat or Animal.Dog) {
    print(type.description)
}

feedAnimal(type: Animal.Cat())
// It's a cat

feedAnimal(type: Animal.Dog())
// It's a dog
```

I want to restrict my function's parameter type to *properties* of specific struct not the struct itself.

Are there any ways to implement this in Swift? If so, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Structs don't have inheritance. You could use a protocol `feedable` to which `Dog` and `Cat` conform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing the functionality of a **protocol**

```
protocol Animal {
    var description : String { get }
}

struct Cat : Animal {
    let description = "It's a cat"
}

struct Dog : Animal {
    let description = "It's a dog"
}


// Restrict its input to properties of struct Animal
func feedAnimal(type: Animal) {
    print(type.description)
}

feedAnimal(type: Cat())
// It's a cat

feedAnimal(type: Dog())
// It's a dog
```

---

You can even declare the `feed` function in a protocol extension

```
protocol Animal {
    var description : String { get }
    func feed()
}

extension Animal {
    func feed() {
        print(self.description)
    }
}

struct Cat : Animal {
    let description = "It's a cat"
}

struct Dog : Animal {
    let description = "It's a dog"
}

Cat().feed()
// It's a cat

Dog().feed()
// It's a dog
```